# using onclick to destroy session

Tags: php, html

When I using onclick property to log out of my page and destroy the session its destroy it before I logging out ... here is the code ....

```
                                <ul>
                                <li> 
                                    <a href="dispUsers.php"> 
                                        Display Users
                                    </a> 
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="DispInfo.php"> 
                                        Display Users Information
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="index.php" onclick="<?= session_destroy();?>">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

what should i do???

Comment: ajax would be an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Because your logic is incorrect. PHP does not run on the clients browser like js does. PHP is a server side language.

You could create a new php file called logout.php, also based on what you have provided you don't need the `onclick` attribute. You can call the logout.php via the `href`.

The logout.php would contain the logout code and the `session_destroy()` function.

If you wish to redirect the user to another page after the logout script you can create a redirect header for that, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it with `jQuery` and `.ajax`. Please read the comments on the php block to understand how to effectively kill a php session.

**logout.php**

```
<?php
if($_GET['logout'])
{
    session_start();
    //remove PHPSESSID from browser
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) )
    setcookie( session_name(), "", time()-3600, "/" );
    //clear session from globals
    $_SESSION = array();
    //clear session from disk
    echo session_destroy() ? "Successfully Logged Out" :  "An error Occurred";
    exit;
}
?>
```

---

**file.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#logout" ).click(function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'logout.php',
            data: ({ logout : 1 }),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $( "#output" ).text(data);
                $( "#logout" ).hide();
            },
            error: function() {
                $( "#output" ).text(data);
            }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="logout"> Logout </button>
<p id="output"></p>
</body>
</html>
```